# set length is not working in hibernate when table is already created

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

employeeDesc column on my EmployeeDetails table has the default length of varchar(255).
Now i want that to be altered.
I have tried giving customised length on persistent class.

```
@Entity
public class EmployeeDetails {
@Id
private int employeeId;
private String employeeName;
private int employeeAge;
@Column (length = 500)
private String employeeDesc;
   // getters and setters
}
```

And this is my hibernate configuration.

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

if i tried to give value more than 255 for the field employeeDesc, I am getting error saying

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'employeeDesc' at row 1
```

Is there any better way to alter the employeeDesc's length without changing "hbm2ddl.auto">update property?

Comment: Why not update the DB directly?

Comment: Nick, we can if it is one time. But we can't go and update each and every time. I want some automated way to do this.

Comment: Like one of the answers said you can use something called Liquibase but I like flyway more. Please read the documentation on their website. Its quite easy to use and very easy to integrate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't update column length during updating/validation. You can try to use [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org). But I am not sure that you will be able to use Hibernate `update` with `Liquibase` .

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Lob annotation. Code would be something like:

```
@Lob
@Column
private String employeeDesc;
```

Visit [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28613_01/apirefs.1211/e24399/javax/persistence/Lob.html) for information

Comment: Hibernate will not change column type during update.

Answer (score 0):

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto value="update"` wont change column definition if it is already existing.

This won't even remove the columns if they are available in table just by removing from your entity.

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto value="update"` can just add new columns / new indexes / new constraints.